# Assistance opening a connection from C# VSTO Excel project to a closed .xlsx file (w/o opening the .xlsx file)

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto

I am trying to convert an Excel AddIn I wrote in VBA into a C# VSTO. Being fairly new to C# and VS this seemed like a good way to expand my skills without having to come up with a new project idea.

One of the features of the original AddIn is it can read multiple closed .xlsx workbooks into memory, do some basic math and output the new data into a new workbook. Originally, this was achieved utilizing an Adodb.Connection.  Currently, I am unable to replicate the connection to the workbooks in the VSTO AddIn.

The workbooks that are being read from need to remain closed. Each workbook has three to five worksheets but I only require data from one of them that has a static name. The columns have headers but they are not very friendly headers like, "Exclusive?  (1=Yes, 0=No)" or "Discharge Date|Time Display". The column names are static but the columns numbers are not. Also, I am only dealing with small amounts of data in each workbook.

So far I have looked at a few different options. LinqToExcel looked promising but fell short because of the horrible column names I am working with. I have also attempted to use an OleDbConnection as well as an Adodb.connection with little success.

This is the code that is successful in VBA.

```
    'Connection
    Dim Cnx As ADODB.Connection: Set Cnx = New ADODB.Connection
    With Cnx
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & fileToCopy & _
           ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;Readonly=False'"
        .Open
    End With

    'Command String
    Dim headerString As String, request_SQL As String
    headerString = "[" & FullName & "]," & "[" & MRN & "]," & "[" & OHFColumnName & "]," & "[" & STSColumnName & "]," & "[" & IRColumnName & "]," & "[" & ERColumnName & "]"
    request_SQL = "SELECT " & headerString & " FROM [" & NewbornsWS & "$] WHERE [" & FullName & "] IS NOT NULL OR [" & OHFColumnName & "] IS NOT NULL;"

    'Create RecordSet
    Dim Rst As ADODB.Recordset: Set Rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    If OpenRecordset(Rst, request_SQL, Cnx) Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 518, Description:=Error518
    End If
```

and

```
Private Function OpenRecordset(ByRef Rst As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal request_SQL As String, ByRef Cnx As ADODB.Connection) As Boolean
    'Error Trapping for the RecordSet
    myCallStack.Push "MonthStats.OpenRecordset"
    Dim backupRequestString As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Rst.Open request_SQL, Cnx, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        OpenRecordset = False
        myCallStack.Pop
        Exit Function
    Else
        Rst.Close
        OpenRecordset = True
        myCallStack.Pop
        Exit Function
    End If
    myCallStack.Pop
End Function
```

Failed Attempts:

My attempt to utilize Adodb in C#. This fails @ cnx.Open(connectionString);.

```
using ADODB;

 internal static BreastFeedingData GetXlFileData(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + fileName +
                    ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;Readonly=False'";
                Connection cnx = new Connection();
                cnx.Open(connectionString);

                Recordset rst = new Recordset();

                string headerString = $"[{MFullName}], [{MMRN}], [{MDDColumName}], [{MOHFColumnName}], [{MSTSColumnNameV}], [{MSTSColumnNameC}], [{MIRColumnName}], [{MERColumnName}]";
                string request_SQL = $"SELECT {headerString} FROM [{MNewbornsWS}$] WHERE [{MFullName}] IS NOT NULL OR [{MOHFColumnName}] IS NOT NULL;";

                rst.Open(request_SQL, cnx, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly, 1);
                BreastFeedingData breastFeedingData = ReadFromData(rst);
                rst.Close();
                return breastFeedingData;
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I also attempted this as well and ran into issues @ cmd.Fill(excelDataSet);

```
private static TStats GetOpenXlFileData(DateTime dateTime, string fileName)
        {
            string connectionString = string.
                Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source={0}; " +
                "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0; HDR = Yes; IMEX = 1; Readonly = False'", fileName);

            OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            string headerString = $"[{MFullName}], [{MMRN}], [{MOHFColumnName}], [{MSTSColumnNameV}], [{MSTSColumnNameC}], [{MIRColumnName}], [{MERColumnName}]";
            string request_SQL = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM [{1}$] WHERE [{2}] IS NOT NULL OR [{3}] IS NOT NULL;",
                headerString, MNewbornsWS, MFullName, MOHFColumnName);

            OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(request_SQL, con);

            con.Open();
            System.Data.DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
            cmd.Fill(excelDataSet);
            DataTable data = excelDataSet.Tables[0];
            TStats stats = ReadFromData(data, dateTime);
            con.Close();
            return stats;
        }
```

I am not sure if my issue is in my code itself or in my VS setup. Please let me know if more information is required. Thank you in advance for any assistance you might have in helping me resolve this issue.

Comment: OleDbConnection is a common way to do this, what specific issues does that code have? (What's the reason for not wanting to read directly via interop+Excel.Application?)

Comment: Doublechecked that `fileName` is correct? Especially the backslash?

Comment: The exception I receive is "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Newborns_3$'." The worksheet is there. The reason for not using the interop is it takes quite a long time to open up multiple workbooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The workbooks that are being read from need to remain closed.

Try this basic function that I quickly wrote.  This is in VB.Net.

`xlsFile` is the closed excel file name with path and `ShName` is the sheet name.

```
Private Function LoadFromFile(xlsFile As String, ShName As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing

    '~~> Get the file data in the datatable
    Try
        '~~> Get data from file
        Using MyConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" &
                                                          xlsFile &
                                                          ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1""")
            MyConnection.Open()

            Dim SheetName As String = ShName & "$"

            Using MyCommand As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & SheetName & "]", MyConnection)
                dt = New DataTable
                MyCommand.Fill(dt)
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "System Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    Return dt
End Function
```

> Access database engine could not find the object 'Newborns_3$'. this is the correct name of the worksheet I am looking for. – Courtland9777 48 mins ago

**Tried and Tested**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim tmpdt As DataTable

        tmpdt = LoadFromFile("C:\Users\routs\Desktop\book1.xlsx", "Newborns_3")

        MessageBox.Show (tmpdt.Rows.Count)
    End Sub

    Private Function LoadFromFile(xlsFile As String, ShName As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing

        '~~> Get the file data in the datatable
        Try
            '~~> Get data from file
            Using MyConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" &
                                                              xlsFile &
                                                              ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1""")
                MyConnection.Open()

                Dim SheetName As String = ShName & "$"

                Using MyCommand As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & SheetName & "]", MyConnection)
                    dt = New DataTable
                    MyCommand.Fill (dt)
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "System Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

        Return dt
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I gave this a try. When creating the new OleDbDataAdapter I keep getting an exception that the Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Newborns_3$'. this is the correct name of the worksheet I am looking for.

Comment: I tried it and it is working fine for me. See the above post. I updated it with the code that I tried.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. Your code is correct. I was getting the error because there are no space allowed anywhere in the file path. Once I changed the folder name that contained the space the issue was resolved.